# Does a doctor who does endoscopies just do endoscopies?

Tags: gastroenterology

I just spent a half hour in a gastroenterologist's office talking with him about my history, problems, diet, etc. and getting a basic physical exam.  He wants to do an upper endoscopy.  Is it normal for the same doctor to do all of the above?  My primary care physician normally writes an order for tests and sends me to the hospital.  I don't see the person doing the actual test until right before and we never talk about anything but the test itself.  Just seems strange to me that the doctor ordering the test would also do it.

Comment: Nothing unusual about it at all. GI docs do endoscopies (but not just endoscopies) so there's no reason for him to send you to someone else.